# Html Font-Size using rem - manual changes for old browsers without overwriting rem value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Edited for clarity]

Reading many other posts on this forum we see it is good practice to set the rem font-size with a default as well. Eg

```
. myclass {
    font-size: 16px; /* default for browsers who have problems with rem */
    font-size: 1.0rem; /* What I want, what I really really want */
}
```

Sometimes in my application, for the older browsers, I would like to change the font-size if the user changes the dimensions of their window (eg clicking the maximize button).

The problem I have is I would normally use the following:

```
$(".myclass").css("font-size", "20px");
```

if I decided I needed the new size of 20px. However remember the pixel size of the font was my **fallback** only if the rem did not work. The correct value was 1.0rem, and I want it to remain that way.

I was going to change my rem values with the code:

```
$("html").css('font-size', "20px");
```

So the question is, how do I retain my prefered 1.0rem values for borwsers that are rem capable, but be able to use

```
$(".myclass").css("font-size", "20px");
```

without overwriting the rem font-size for myclass?

**Note:** I am not using @media as my webpage requires a lot more precision than that. It would be impractical to have a @media for every couple of pixels change required in the font size for my setting.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking...

Comment: "_(...) change stuff on the fly when the user rescales the window..._". Are you looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)?

Comment: Yeah, Rewind, I think you're looking for `@media` queries for CSS. Steer clear of Javascript whenever CSS will do. This let's you do things like `@media (min-width: 1024px) { body { font-size: 16px; } }`. (`@media` works with IE9+.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited the question to clarify things and also say why @media is not practical in my case.